# Tabulating average value through spatial join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, spatial-join, average

Previous ArcGIS user and have now switched over to QGIS for a project. I am performing a spatial join of two shapefiles - one of census tracts and the other of zctas. In ArcGIS you can set the merge rule to average the values of data in one of the original layers by the other in the joined layer. Is this possible in QGIS?

When I perform the join, I am seeing values for the field originally in the census tract data in the zcta (larger) units -- but I'm assuming this is the first value found, right? Any clarification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial explains how to summarize attributes when performing a spatial join.

[QGIS Spatial Join tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful as I was previously doing Join Attribute by Location instead of Join Attribute by Location (Summarize)